# Python string comparison not evaluating as expected

Tags: python, string, comparison, evaluation

I have a date in one file and one in another. They look like this:

> log1.log -> "06/11/2017"

and

> log2.log -> "06/11/2017"

Specifically looking for matches like this, I've written this bit:

```
if row != date:
  pass
elif row == date:
  print("match found")
```

And I have already tried making the logic, rather than check for inequality, check for equality; but it didn't work. I've also exported the values found into a new text file and checked for whitespace or newlines which would be hard to detect in a terminal. No dice.

Printing the dates to the terminal confirms that they are indeed matches.

Example output:

`[#] 06/13/2017 06/13/2017`

When I print them both with a space in between them and that hash notation to keep the printout looking organized.

Last thing I tried is superficially converting both of them to strings in the comparison. Am I nuts? What's going on here?

I can provide anything but the data itself. However we're talking literally just .log files with lines I've used split to grab and so I offer the output above to rule out any data issues.

edit: when you edited my post, you absolutely murdered my grammar and readability dude. it was gibberish as far as the English language is concerned when you were done with it. Let's leave it alone for now, k? The subject of the sentence is "the logic". What I've edited back is just fine. And you do not need to disclaim pluralization on "whitespace". It's already implied there could be multiple instances of it.

Comment: is there only a single line in each log file? Are you trying to compare lines by line numbers or one line to the whole file?

Comment: They are maybe invisible characters in your strings. try converting them into bytes and compare the results.

Comment: Nah multiple for each log and every other line in log2 is blank. I'll pastebin the code. https://pastebin.com/xP0pibEc

Comment: @BoilingFire doing this now.

Comment: Hi, i think the problem is related with the read function, and maybe with the white spaces in file, can you write your file read code to see the way that are you using?

Comment: can you try `row.strip() == date.strip()` ? could be a trailing linefeed or space problem.

Comment: Encoding with codecs.encode(str,"rot-13") didn't get the expected result.

Comment: @RicardoMartínez I'm sorry can you elaborate, not sure what you mean by "write your file read code"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Nope :(

Comment: Try replacing `print("  [#] "+str(row)+' '+str(date))` with this: `print([ord(x) for x in row], [ord(x) for x in date])` - this will print actual ASCII codes for characters in both your strings.

Comment: @Błotosmętek We're on to something. This is what I got back `[0, 48, 0, 54, 0, 47, 0, 49, 0, 52, 0, 47, 0, 50, 0, 48, 0, 49, 0, 55, 0] [48, 54, 47, 49, 51, 47, 50, 48, 49, 55]` and since that's REALLY ugly I will save you time and mention they do not match as ASCII

Comment: Also the first one it finds does not have the zero in the beginning of the first array. I cannot stress enough that these strings look identical when they print.

Comment: Well, that settles it - `date` comes from a file that's just ASCII (48 stands for `0`, 54 for `6` etc.), but row does **not**. It is likely UCS2/UTF-16 encoding, and you should declare that encoding while `open`ing that file.

Comment: I'll do just that and I will come back to let you know if it worked so that you can answer the question in a comment. :)

Comment: @Błotosmętek using `k = open("keyevents.log", encoding="utf-16")` it didnt fix the evaluation. I've tried to convert the first file to utf-16 as well but it gave an error `raise UnicodeError("UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM") UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM`

Comment: Well, it seem it is UTF-16 sans BOM. Probably a broken app that produced this log. You can try converting the line after reading it, ie after `for line in f:` add `line = line.encode('Latin1').decode('UTF-16')` (or, if that doesn't produce expected result, 'UTF-16LE')

Comment: @Błotosmętek hey. I found out what it was. You're correct; just took some fine details to figure it out. `k = open("keyevents.log", encoding="utf-16-le")` fixed it, the '-le' in the encoding type fixed it due to BOM reading I believe. Go ahead and answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `encoding='UTF-16LE'` argument when `open`ing the file.